# Create an array from Dataframe comumn

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I'm beginning with Python.
I want to create an new array which will contains all words store from one columns in a dataframe.

This column already contains array with words :

Here is an example:

```py
df['Body_A'].values[0]
```

the output:

> ['p',  'open',  'terminal',  'application',  'gt',  'utility',  'gt',
> 'terminal',  'type',  'p',  'pre',  'code',  'locate',
> 'insertfonthere',  'br',  'code',  'pre',  'p',  'spit',  'every',
> 'file',  'p',  'p',  'warning',  'may',  'alot',  'wade',  'p']

I've tried to store everything doing this:

```
rows = []
[rows + row['Body_A'] for index, row in df.iterrows()]
```

My idea was to store in a new array rows the values from every row from my dataframe.

But when I want to print rows :

```
print(rows)
```

It returns me an empty.
I don't realize what I'm doing wrong could help tell me more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can flat the list using nested list comprehension

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'fine'], ['How', 'are', 'you', '?']]})
flat_list = [item for sublist in df['a'] for item in sublist] 

df::
    a
0   [Hello, I, am, fine]
1   [How, are, you, ?]
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'fine', 'How', 'are', 'you', '?']
```